# Pressing a button to add an element to an array in LabVIEW

Tags: arrays, labview

Is it possible to add an element to an array by pressing a button?
In such a way that the first press enters a '1' element, the second a '2' and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Given how LabVIEW works, your question is borderline nonsensical. I'm going to try to untangle a few concepts that you seem to have conflated. I hope this doesn't come off as insulting -- I see genuine confusion and I'm hoping I can help.

First of all, what do you mean by "an array"? Do you mean the value on a wire or the value you see in a control on the front panel? LabVIEW's front panels are just the display of values computed in the block diagrams. In a running program, you never directly manipulate the values in any control. You can read the value, manipulate it, and then write it back to the control.

So, on the block diagram, yes, you can add an element to an array by using the "Build Array" node. And then you could display that value in an array indicator on the front panel.

You can have a button on the front panel that triggers an event. If that event code adds to an array, then you display that value in an indicator, then, yes, you can have a button that adds an element to an array. The code would look something like the code below. Notice that I never "add" an element to the array indicator. The array indicator simply updates every time the loop runs with whatever the computed value happens to be.

PS: the other frame of the event structure is just a "Stop" button handler.

[image: Block diagram of loop that adds elements to an array]
[image: Front panel of the above]

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by srm works fine.
Just a note: be careful with the tunnel options for the wires. If you add some other event cases on the Event Structure, you should disable the tunnel option: Use Default value. Otherwise, when this new event cases are handled, this reset the shift register array value.

[See screeshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voL98.png)